# Use dropna on subset for clean-up

Tags: python, pandas

I need do check for completeness on a subset of my pandas.DataFrame.
Currently I am doing this:

```
special = df[df.kind=='special']
others = df[df.kind!='special']

special = special.dropna(how='any')

all = pd.concat([special, others])
```

I am wondering if I'm not missing anything of the powerful Pandas API that makes this possible in one line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to Pandas from where I'm writing, however [`pd.DataFrame.isnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) checks whether things are null, and [`pd.DataFrame.any()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) can check conditions by row.

Consequently, if you do

```
(df.kind != 'special') | ~df.isnull().any(axis=1)
```

this should give the rows you want to keep. You can just use normal indexing on this expression. 
It would be interesting to see if this at all speeds things up (it checks things on more rows than your solution does, but might create smaller DataFrames).

Comment: I don't think your answer does the same as mine. I am NOT dropping incomplete data for non-special kinds. I think your's does.

Comment: Oh, it's a mixup of whether the drop is on the specials or not, no? Thanks. Please see if it's now OK.

Comment: That might be it, thanks! Try it out tomorrow. I think I did not come up with this because I'm not used to think with OR filters :)

Comment: @K.-MichaelAye Actually, it's possible to simplify the expression a bit (see update). Clarify is subjective, but to me it looks a bit clearer than the code in your question.